# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. Update then Crash

Tags: android, kotlin

I am faced with a problem and I don't know why.

```
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views
```

in my fragment, I have a method OnUserImageClicked

```
override fun OnUserNumberClicked(photo: UserPicture) {

    subscriptions.add(
        mRepository.userPicture()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe {
                userListener.updateUserNumber()
            }
    )
}
```

userListener is an interface in other presenter which have these following method

```
interface UserListener {
    fun updateUserNumber()
}

private var userListener = object : UserListener {
    override fun updateUserPicture() {
        fetchUserNumber()
    }
}
```

and in the presenter I have the following method fetchNumberOfPictureSelected()

```
fun fetchUserNumber(): Int {

    subscriptions.add(mRepository.getUserNumber()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe (
            { number -> view?.updateNumber(number) },
            { // ErrorCode here }
        )
    )
}
```

then my fragment I have this following code : 
userNumberUpdate.text = number

So on my emulator, when I Click on "OnUserNumberClicked" method, the number is updated but the app crash after.
Can you help me ?

Comment: You'll need to add method `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`.

Comment: subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) Means your task will get excuted in background thread. And with this you are trying to update the UI which is causing the app to crash. Just add .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) after subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to observe UI calls on the main thread using `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`.

```
override fun OnUserNumberClicked(photo: UserPicture) {
    subscriptions.add(
        mRepository.userPicture()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                userListener.updateUserNumber()
            }
    )
}
```